# Pass value from javascript function in client side to server side in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

The web form has grid view which contains Delete link. On clicking the link, confirmation message should be displayed. I am using function which displays the confirmation dialog box. On clicking OK button, the respective record should be deleted. How can I pass some value on clicking OK button in the dialog box to perform delete operation?

```
void ConfirmMsg(string cMsg)
{
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
    String cstext = "confirm('" + cMsg + "');";
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "PopupScript", cstext, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use this line in place of ur delete button.nothing needed:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete the Company Information?')" CausesValidation="False" 
                                        CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a link button as Delete link and

```
OnClick = your delete function

OnClientClick = return Confirm("Confirmation message")
```

if user clicks OK, the function in OnClick will execute. Otherwise it will not